# How to prove the correction of derive on reg_exp

Tags: coq

It's a question in software foundation, logic foundation, IndProp.v

Here is some definitions.

```
Inductive reg_exp (T : Type) : Type :=
  | EmptySet
  | EmptyStr
  | Char (t : T)
  | App (r1 r2 : reg_exp T)
  | Union (r1 r2 : reg_exp T)
  | Star (r : reg_exp T).

Inductive exp_match {T} : list T -> reg_exp T -> Prop :=
  | MEmpty : [] =~ EmptyStr
  | MChar x : [x] =~ (Char x)
  | MApp s1 re1 s2 re2
             (H1 : s1 =~ re1)
             (H2 : s2 =~ re2)
           : (s1 ++ s2) =~ (App re1 re2)
  | MUnionL s1 re1 re2
                (H1 : s1 =~ re1)
              : s1 =~ (Union re1 re2)
  | MUnionR re1 s2 re2
                (H2 : s2 =~ re2)
              : s2 =~ (Union re1 re2)
  | MStar0 re : [] =~ (Star re)
  | MStarApp s1 s2 re
                 (H1 : s1 =~ re)
                 (H2 : s2 =~ (Star re))
               : (s1 ++ s2) =~ (Star re)
  where "s =~ re" := (exp_match s re).

Definition derives d := forall a re, is_der re a (d a re).

Fixpoint derive (a : ascii) (re : reg_exp ascii) : reg_exp ascii :=
  match re with
  | EmptySet => EmptySet
  | EmptyStr => EmptySet
  | Char c => if (eqb a c) then EmptyStr else EmptySet
  | App re1 re2 => Union (App (derive a re1) re2) (if match_eps re1
                                                   then derive a re2
                                                   else EmptySet)
  | Union re1 re2 => Union (derive a re1) (derive a re2)
  | Star re => App (derive a re) (Star re)
  end.
```

And the Lemma I have to prove is

```
Lemma derive_corr : derives derive.
```

I was struck when the `re` is `Star re`.

As `a:s =~ Star re` -> `s1 ++ s2 = a :: s /\ s1 =~ re /\ s2 =~ Star re`

If `s1 <> []`, it can be solved easily.

But when `s1 == []`, it seems come into a endless loop(I have to same thing again on s2). I guess I can make it by recur, but I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably prove a "better" inversion that the one that the inversion tactic of your hypothesis gives you, something that intuitively says that the left string of `MStarApp` cannot be forever empty. Proving such stronger inversions is quite usual in this kind of settings.

Here a possibility is to show that if `a :: s =~ Star re`, then there exists `s1` and `s2` such that `s = s1 ++ s2 /\ a :: s1 =~ re /\ s2 =~ Star re`.

Comment: I have tried this. But I found I got into the same situation again…. I’ll try it again later.

Comment: These kind of inversions are quite hard to get right, so it’s no surprise if you have to struggle here. You might want to look at Program’s `dependent inversion` for a tactic that might help you.

Comment: Well, I still don't know how to do that. When I try to `dependent inversion` `a :: s =~ Star re`. Coq response "Current goal does not depend on Hre."

Comment: Ah, sorry, I meant `dependent induction`.

Comment: I made it! Thank you very much!!!!